# Servlet Printout error

Tags: java, mysql, servlets

I want to print out a column from my MySQL database. I have a calendar system, where you can choose a "from" date "to" date. When you choose the time period, it should print out the COLUMN "Allday_hours" from MySQL database. I am using a javascript, AJAX and JSON. This is calling my servlet. The first servlet I made does not print anything out, but it gave me a success. Therefore with help from someone on stack overflow the code got changed, and it looks more correct, but now it gives me a failure. I made 2 videos of it. Can anyone see what is wrong here? The javascript code I used for both servlets

Best Regards
Mads

The first servlet where it is success:
Video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UzdvQ4B9clw&feature=youtu.be

Servlet code:

```
package WorkPackage;

import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

@WebServlet("/getHoursSQL")
public class getHoursSQL extends HttpServlet{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(request, response);
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) 
        throws ServletException, IOException{

        String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/NekiWork";
        Connection connection=null;
        res.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = res.getWriter();

        try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", ""); 
            String sql = "SELECT *, (Day_hours + (Day_minutes / 100)) AS Allday_hours FROM Workdata";
            PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.execute(sql);
            pst.close();
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e){

            out.println("Couldn't load database driver: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            out.println("SQLException caught: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            out.println(e);
        }
        finally {

            try {
                if (connection != null) connection.close();
            }
            catch (SQLException ignored){
                out.println(ignored);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This video and code is the latest one where it gives me an error. I have made // where new code was added:
Video:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6DO1GnjDRWk

Servlet code:

```
package WorkPackage;

import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

@WebServlet("/getHoursSQL")
public class getHoursSQL extends HttpServlet{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(request, response);
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) 
        throws ServletException, IOException{

        String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/NekiWork";
        Connection connection=null;
        String all_day_hours = null;                            // new code
        res.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");          // new code
        res.getWriter().write(all_day_hours);                   // new code

        try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", ""); 
            String sql = "SELECT *, (Day_hours + (Day_minutes / 100)) AS Allday_hours FROM Workdata";
            PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery(sql);

            if(rs.next()){                                      // new code
                 all_day_hours = rs.getString("Allday_hours");  // new code
            }                                                   // new code
            pst.close();
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e){

            System.out.println("Couldn't load database driver: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            System.out.println("SQLException caught: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        finally {

            try {
                if (connection != null) connection.close();
            }
            catch (SQLException ignored){
                System.out.println(ignored);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Javascript code:

```
<form>
          <input id="startDate" />

          <input id="endDate" />
    </form>
    <div id="result"></div>
    <script>

    $(function(){
        $("#startDate").datepicker({
            dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
            onSelect: function(dateText,inst){
                alert(dateText);

                $.ajax({
                      url: "../getHoursSQL",
                      type: "post",
                      data: JSON,
                      success: function(data){
                          alert("success");
                          $("#result").html(data);

                      },
                      error:function(){
                          alert("failure");
                          $("#result").html('there is error while submit');
                      }  
                    });
            }
        });
    });

    $(function(){
            $("#endDate").datepicker({
                dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
                onSelect: function(dateText,inst){
                    alert(dateText);

                    $.ajax({
                          url: "../getHoursSQL",
                          type: "post",
                          data: JSON,
                          success: function(data){
                              alert("success");
                              $("#result").html(data);
                          },
                          error:function(){
                              alert("failure");
                              $("#result").html('there is error while submit');
                          }  
                        });
                }
            });
        });

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Right answer:

```
package WorkPackage;

import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

@WebServlet("/getHoursSQL")
public class getHoursSQL extends HttpServlet{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        doPost(request, response);
    }

    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res) 
        throws ServletException, IOException{

        String connectionURL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/NekiWork";
        Connection connection=null;
                                // new code
                    // new code

        try {

            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(connectionURL, "root", ""); 
            String sql = "SELECT *, (Day_hours + (Day_minutes / 100)) AS Allday_hours FROM Workdata";
            PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(sql);

            ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery(sql);
            String all_day_hours = null;    
            if(rs.next()){                                      // new code
                 all_day_hours = rs.getString("Allday_hours");  // new code
            }                                                   // new code
            pst.close();
            res.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");          // new code
            res.getWriter().write(all_day_hours);   
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e){

            System.out.println("Couldn't load database driver: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        catch(SQLException e){
            System.out.println("SQLException caught: " + e.getMessage());
        }
        catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        finally {

            try {
                if (connection != null) connection.close();
            }
            catch (SQLException ignored){
                System.out.println(ignored);
            }
        }
    }
}
```